# ValueError: high <= 0 , LTSM

Tags: python, generator

When running the following:

---

```
def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):

'''Generator function for creating random batches of training-data.'''


# Infinite loop.
while True:
    # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
    x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
    x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

    # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
    y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
    y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

    # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
    for i in range(batch_size):
        # Get a random start-index.
        # This points somewhere into the training-data.
        idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)
        
        # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
        x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
        y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[idx:idx+sequence_length]
    
    yield (x_batch, y_batch)
batch_size = 256
sequence_length = 2 * 7 * 8
```

---

```
generator = batch_generator(batch_size=batch_size,
                            sequence_length=2 * 7 * 8)
```

---

```
x_batch, y_batch = next(generator)
```

This block of code returns a  ValueError: high <= 0

Here is the error that I am receiving:

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11424/2071659211.py in 
> ----> 1 x_batch, y_batch = next(generator)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11424/1112051746.py in
> batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length)
> 18             # Get a random start-index.
> 19             # This points somewhere into the training-data.
> ---> 20             idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)
> 21
> 22             # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
>
> mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint()
>
> _bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32()
>
> ValueError: high <= 0

Comment: If you encounter an exception, please provide the traceback of the exception.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the entire error message.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code and expected output. Here, `256 sequence_length` is invalid syntax and it looks like everything after `yield (x_batch, y_batch)` is indented one level too high. As well, these names are not defined: `num_x_signals, num_y_signals, num_train, x_train_scaled, y_train_scaled`, plus `import numpy as np`. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Please use code formatting for errors. Blockquote formatting messes up the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm late, but nevertheless

> ValueError: high <= 0

It happens because here:

```
idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)
```

You input one argument instead two.

I think it can be useful: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `num_train <= sequence_length` leads to a zero or negative value being passed as an argument to the `randint()` in the line `idx = np.random.randint(num_train - sequence_length)`

`ValueError: high <= 0` occurs when the argument of `randint()` is 0 or negative, when a single argument is used.